# Show JOptionPane on Enter key being pressed while JTextPane has input focus

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, enter

I have a `JTextPane` component that I am using to output some text and allowing the user to input data to the same component. Is there is a way to implement a functionality such that if user press Enter key, show a `JOptionPane`?

Comment: What component is supposed to have focus when the user presses enter, the text pane or the button? If the text pane, the button has nothing to do with it. If the button, the text pane has nothing to do with it.

Comment: I misread the question. D'oh!

Comment: its the textpanel

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, I would guess the OP meant to say "Enter key on the keyboard" so the solution to create a custom Key Binding for the Enter KeyStroke would be correct.

Comment: @camickr: thank you for that

Answer (score 3):

Consider setting the Key Bindings on the JTextPane such that when the enter key is pressed, `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER`, it triggers an AbstractAction that displays the JOptionPane. As with all key bindings, this will mean getting the JTextPanes InputMap and ActionMap and binding them together with some constant key String.

You can find the Key Bindings tutorial here: [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TextPaneBinding extends JPanel {
    private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();

    public TextPaneBinding() {

        // get the enter key stroke and create a key String for binding from it
        KeyStroke enterKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0);
        String bindingKey = enterKeyStroke.toString();

        // get our input map and action map
        int condition = JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED;
        InputMap inputMap = textPane.getInputMap(condition); // only want when focused
        ActionMap actionMap = textPane.getActionMap();

        // set up the binding of the key stroke to the action
        inputMap.put(enterKeyStroke, bindingKey);
        actionMap.put(bindingKey, new MyAction());

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        add(new JScrollPane(textPane));
    }

    private class MyAction extends AbstractAction {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String message = "This is the JOptionPane Message";
            String title = "My Title";
            int messageType = JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(textPane, message, title, messageType);
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        TextPaneBinding mainPanel = new TextPaneBinding();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextPaneBinding");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```